# How to insert a value in SQL anywhere?

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

I can't insert a value using this code:

```
 insert into t_category_values (CategoryCode,
 CategoryValueCode, CategoryValue) values(2, 1, 1);
```

error msg

```
no primary key
```

Comment: Wrong Query: show your table structure and tell me what u exact want to send??

Comment: insert values on CategoryCode, CategoryValueCode and CategoryValue..

Comment: @Moon `CategoryCode, CategoryValueCode and CategoryValue` is attribute name or table name?? what is your table name ? is it `t_category_values`

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Anywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is wrong it should be:

```
INSERT INTO `DBA`.`t_category_values` 
(CategoryCode, CategoryValueCode, CategoryValue)
VALUES(1, 1, "aaa");
```

See here for more help: [Sql Insert Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_%28SQL%29)

---

**Edit:**

Your query and error:

> insert into t_category_values
>   (CategoryCode,  CategoryValueCode,
>   CategoryValue) values(2, 1, 1);
>
> no primary key

In insert while specifying to insert in few column instead of all in table you must have to include primary key. That means in your one of CategoryCode,  CategoryValueCode, CategoryValue should be primary key or include fourth column that is primary key in table.

Comment: Yeah, or he wants a ``insert into ... select from.`` tho this might be the likelist idea.

Comment: @Macro: thats why I updated it and tell OP to try updated query.

Answer (score 3):

```
insert into `DBA`.`t_category_values` (`CategoryCode`, `CategoryValueCode`, `CategoryValue`) values(1, 1, "aaa");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this (**edited** because you use Sybase SQL Anywhere):

```
INSERT INTO dba.t_category_values
(CategoryCode, CategoryValueCode, CategoryValue)
VALUES(1, 1, 'aaa');
```

**EDITED:**
from [Sybase web page](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-pbarc/conn5/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/4620;pt=1435/%2a):
Adding rows to a table

Suppose that a new eastern sales department is created, with the same manager as the current Sales department. You can add this information to the database using the following INSERT statement:

```
 INSERT
 INTO department ( dept_id, dept_name, dept_head_id )
 VALUES ( 220, 'Eastern Sales', 902 )
```

If you make a mistake and forget to specify one of the columns, SQL Anywhere reports an error.

The NULL value is a special value used to indicate that something is either not known or not applicable. Some columns are allowed to contain the NULL value, and others are not.

Comment: Syntax error on line 1, column 13: Illegal character "`" (96)

INSERT INTO

Comment: @MoonFang: Backticks **`** (ascii 096) are used in MySQL to delimit tables or fields names... are you using MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

The INSERT goes like this:

```
INSERT INTO `DBA`.`t_category_values`
(CategoryCode, CategoryValueCode, CategoryValue) 
VALUES (1, 1, "aaa");
```

1. No "double quotes" around table names, backticks are allowed. `DBA` is the database, `t_category_values` is the table.
2. Name the columns you want to fill
3. Add 'values' followed by the values for those columns.

If you want to insert data **from another table**, use a SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO `DBA`.`t_category_values`
(CategoryCode, CategoryValueCode, CategoryValue) 
SELECT (CategoryCode, CategoryValueCode, CategoryValue) 
FROM `DBA`.`old_category_values`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert query eg:-

```
Insert into `tableName`(field1, field2, field3) values ('value1', 'value2', 'value3');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error "No Primary Key" because you have not specified a valid unique primary key.

Your table must be 4 columns.

```
INSERT INTO t_category_values (PRIMARY_KEY, CategoryCode, CategoryValueCode, CategoryValue) 
VALUES(pkey_value_here, 2, 1, 1);
```

The only time you dont need to specify the primary key column is when the primary key is an auto increment value. If it is an auto increment column the INSERT will automatically fill in that value for you and you dont need to worry about it.